# win10 high contrast theme file open dialog context menu is empty

Tags: fileopendialog

Since Windows 10, the (Vista+) file dialog generated by

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfd));
```

does not show the dialog context menu when in a high contrast theme.  It worked as expected in Win81, and Win7, but not Win10 (none of Win10: since the original, up to most-recent 1607).

Foobar2000, an app, just recently fixed the problem (as of v1.3.12, at least).  Here are two pics showing the problem in two versions, the bad on is v1.2.3, but I am sure as recently as the 1.3.beta it was bad.

Below these are winspy info on the only real difference I can spot, in Properties.  The Win10 system File Explorer has the same '0000A916 (Atom)' property that is in the current FB2k (but not present in previous FB2ks).

How can I get the Win10-like File Open dialog?  Notice the Vista-like graphics are not in the new version (e.g., see the back and forward arrow buttons).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This third link did not make it with 0 rep pts.

Comment: I thought the problem was theme related.  I compared the manifests between the two fb2ks.  And there it was.  The supportedOS element is needed.  The only one I care about is the one for Win10.  I've included the .manifest I use.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem was theme related.  I compared the manifests between the two fb2ks.  And there it was.  The supportedOS element is needed.  The only one I care about is the one for Win10.  I've included the .manifest I use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"></supportedOS>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```